# how to get the scope of wicket ids when defined inside a submit button

Tags: java, wicket

I have two text boxes to read input.  Once the page is submitted, I would like to display the data in a table. I am facing issue while load the widget; it says dataView is not defined and also the table id is not defined.  However, I defined this inside the submit method. The code is below. Please help me.

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    private String memberNumber,lossNumber;
    ArrayList <AssignmentDB> list = new ArrayList<AssignmentDB>(); int flag=0;

    public HomePage(){
        list.add(new AssignmentDB("1234","001","1678","10/june//2013"));
        PropertyModel memberIdModel=new PropertyModel(this,"memberNumber");
        PropertyModel lossIdModel=new PropertyModel(this,"lossNumber");
        TextField memberIdField = new TextField("memberId",memberIdModel);
        TextField lossIdField = new TextField("lossId",lossIdModel);
        Form form=new Form("form1"){
            public void onSubmit(){
        list.add(new AssignmentDB("1234","001","1678","10/june//2013"));
        list.add(new AssignmentDB("1235","003","1678","13/june//2013"));
        DataView<List<AssignmentDB>> dataView = new DataView<List<AssignmentDB>>("AssignmentList", new ListDataProvider(list)) {

                        public void populateItem(Item<List<AssignmentDB>> item) {
                AssignmentDB lists = (AssignmentDB) item.getModelObject();
                        if (lists.getMemberId().equals(memberNumber)){
                         if(lists.getLossId().equals(lossNumber)){
          flag=1;
         item.add(new Label("AOmemberId", lists.getMemberId()));
         item.add(new Label("AOlossId", lists.getLossId()));
         item.add(new Label("AOassignmentId", lists.getAssignmentId()));
         item.add(new Label("AOdol", lists.getDOL()));
         }
              }
    }
    };

    if (flag==0)
    System.out.println("no matches");
        form.add(dataView);
        form.add(memberIdField);
        form.add(lossIdField);
        add(form);
    }

    public void setMemberNumber(String x)
    {
        this.memberNumber=x;
    }

    public void setLossNumber(String x)
    {
        this.lossNumber=x;
    }

    public String getMemberNumber(){
        return this.memberNumber;
    }

    public String getLossNumber(){
        return this.lossNumber;
    }
}
```

**homepage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>EstimateSearcher</title>
</head>
<body>

<form wicket:id="form1">
Member Number <input type="text" wicket:id="memberId"><br/>
Loss Number   <input type="text" wicket:id="lossId"><br/>
<input type="submit" value=search> 
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>MemberNo</th>
      <th>LossNo</th>
      <th>AssignmentNo</th>
      <th>dol</th>
    </tr>
   <div wicket:id="AssignmentList">
     <tr>
       <td wicket:id="AOmemberId"></td>
       <td wicket:id="AOlossId"></td>
       <td wicket:id="AOassignmentId"></td>
    //<td> <a href="#" wicket:id="AssignmentIdLink"><span wicket:id="AOassignmentId">[Address]</span></a> </td>
       <td wicket:id="AOdol"></td>
     </tr>
   </div>
  </table>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the table outside your submit function because all html wicket:id's should be filled when page is rendered (except the ones with an invisible parent). What you can do is create and add the dataview with an empty list and then use ajax to update your list and the rerender the list:

```
form.add(new AjaxButton("ajax-button", form)
{
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
    {
        list.add(new AssignmentDB("1234","001","1678","10/june//2013"));
        list.add(new AssignmentDB("1235","003","1678","13/june//2013"));
        // repaint the dataView
        target.add(dataView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
    {
        // error handling
    }
});
```

Second easier thing you can do is create a constructor with the list you want to show and do `setResponsPage(new HomePage(listYouWantToUse));` in you forms `onSubmit()`.

Comment: Martin how to create a data view with an emptylist.please share some examples.

Comment: see [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/A+Simple+DataView+Example) example. The list in this example can stay empty and everything still works fine. You html is already correct.

Comment: yes it has been worked...once i add the code for empty list as like in the example